# How to hide navigation bar, status and action bar in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using this code but only navigation bar hides except it nothing hides

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        
actionBar?.hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `themes` file:

```
<style name="xxx" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">    //remove action bar
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>        //remove status bar
```